# Best way quickly try different fonts when editing Text?

Tags: interface, font

Most graphics programs (e.g. Photoshop) have a way to quickly step through different fonts after you type some text by hitting the up and down arrows. Given that there are potentially thousands of fonts to sample, being able to quickly step through fonts is a necessary function to be productive.

When working with Text in blender, the Properties Panel > Text > Font menu shows Regular, Bold, Italic, and Bold & Italic font selectors. This interface allows me to sample a single font with 2 clicks and an enter keystroke. No up/down arrow keys for trying out every font. This UI is extremely inefficient!

Is there a more efficient way to sample many fonts while still being able to view the output in the 3d viewport? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know whether this helps you, but in the open font dialog, you can click on this button (display thumbnails)

[image]

and you can see a preview of fonts, which is pretty helpful.

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks! Much better than the default guess and check workflow!

Comment: Woah I just saw that this became the new default in blender 3.1! I wonder if your answer inspired that update!

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, Blender doesn't load up fonts beforehand, and you can't load more than one font at a time. It does have the advantage of preventing long loading times.